# Why Odoo gives PicklingError while update request.session

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, pickle, odoo-8

Why it gives me an error like this I am just updating simple dictionary. 
It works fine without request.session but it generates this error while update request.session.

```
   @api.multi
    def graph_view(self):
        vals = {}
        if self.x_axis and self.y_axis and self.range_period and self.range_selection:
            vals.update({'id': self.id,
                         'x_axis': self.x_axis,
                         'y_axis': self.y_axis,
                         'range_period': self.range_period,
                         'range_selection': self,
                         'graph_type': 'pie',
                         'model': self
        else:
            raise Warning('Please check the graph') 
        request.session.update(vals)
        res = self.env['ir.model.data'].get_object_reference('pan_pos', 'graph_form_view')
        return {
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_id': res[1],
            'res_model': 'report.sales',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'current'
        }
```

Error Log:

```
2016-12-10 09:16:09,960 31071 ERROR pan_28_11 werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 180, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 168, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/acespritech/ERP/odoo_8/openerp/service/server.py", line 291, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/acespritech/ERP/odoo_8/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/acespritech/ERP/odoo_8/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/acespritech/ERP/odoo_8/openerp/http.py", line 1292, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/acespritech/ERP/odoo_8/openerp/http.py", line 1266, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 591, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/acespritech/ERP/odoo_8/openerp/http.py", line 1266, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 591, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/acespritech/ERP/odoo_8/openerp/http.py", line 1444, in dispatch
    response = self.get_response(httprequest, result, explicit_session)
  File "/home/acespritech/ERP/odoo_8/openerp/http.py", line 1389, in get_response
    self.session_store.save(httprequest.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/contrib/sessions.py", line 244, in save
    dump(dict(session), f, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1376, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
    save(cls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 300, in save
    self.save_global(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 754, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'openerp.api.sales'>: it's not found as openerp.api.sales
```

Please help me to solve.
Thanks.

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your code, i've edited your question, hope that's what you intended?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? the problem you're having is that `werkzeug` tries to pickle an unpicklable object (in this case an instance of `openerp.api.sales`). Python can't pickle the class, read this https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled  it should be of help

Comment: thanks @danidee, I got the error, the dictionary what I am preparing contains the objects type value which is generating this error, I converted that to the string, and now its working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dictionary

> **vals**

contains the wrong value, The self gives the model object which gives only object model if no record found and that gives an error of pickling because the pickle object can not support to model type object.

Converted to the string to the object model by type casting. Solves the error.